# Index was outside the bounds of the array fix when splitting from a .txt file

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to split my text that is read from a txt file using `/` and `*`.

However, I browse for the file and `'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'` comes up!

Any help would be appreciated

```
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{

    string fileToOpen = ofd.FileName;

    System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileToOpen);
    string fileContent = sr.ReadLine();
    string[] items = fileContent.Split('*').ToArray<string>();
    string[] buffer;

    foreach (string s in items)
    {
        ListViewItem lv = new ListViewItem();
        buffer = s.Split('/').ToArray<string>();
        lv.Text = items[0].ToString();
        lv.SubItems.Add(items[1].ToString());
        lv.SubItems.Add(items[2].ToString());
        lv.SubItems.Add(items[3].ToString());
        listView1.Items.Add(lv);
        lv.Text = buffer[0];

        lv.SubItems.Add(buffer[1]);
        lv.SubItems.Add(buffer[2]);
        listView1.Items.Add(lv);
    }
}
```

is my code, thanks!

Comment: On what line do you get the error?  You have several array references in the code.  Clearly (at least) one of them is referencing an array element which doesn't exist.  What are the runtime values of the relevant variables when that happens?

Comment: How can you sure that `items` has 4 elements inside it as you are accessing `item[3]`.

Comment: `Split` already returns a `string` array, Stop calling `ToArray<string>()`. You should post your sample text file. Without looking at it my only guess is you are having `Empty` entries after split, use split like: `fileContent.Split(new []{'*'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`

Comment: Also `ToString()` is totally useless on strings...

Answer (score 2):

Within the foreach loop, you are splitting the string again with `'/'` as

```
 buffer = s.Split('/').ToArray<string>();
```

If no `'/'` found in above string (`s`) your buffer may not have `2/3` items and so

```
lv.SubItems.Add(buffer[1]);
lv.SubItems.Add(buffer[2]);
```

above lines could cause index out of bound error.

Or it could be due to:

```
lv.SubItems.Add(items[1].ToString());
lv.SubItems.Add(items[2].ToString());
lv.SubItems.Add(items[3].ToString());
```

Array Index should always be less than the length (or number of items) in the array.

You can split your string using both `'/'` and `'*'` at the same time as;

```
fileContent.Split(new [] {"*", "/"}, StringSplitOptions.None).ToArray<string>();
```

Comment: hm, i want to make it split words with / and split lines with *, is what i've done wrong? (i assume it is )

Comment: Splitting is okay but you should make sure `index < Array.Length` before using it.

Answer (score 2):

Use items.Count to make sure how many element exists in items array. And use the index starting from 0 to less than items.Count.

i.e. code should be like this:

```
foreach (string s in items)
{
    ListViewItem lv = new ListViewItem();
    buffer = s.Split('/').ToArray<string>();
    lv.Text = items[0].ToString();
    for(int i=0; i<items.Count; i++)
    {
       lv.SubItems.Add(items[i].ToString());
    }
    listView1.Items.Add(lv);
    lv.Text = buffer[0];

    lv.SubItems.Add(buffer[1]);
    lv.SubItems.Add(buffer[2]);
    listView1.Items.Add(lv);
}
```

Comment: for some reason its chucking up an error for the '<' symbol ;o

Comment: Sorry for mistake, use this code for(int i=0; i<items.Length; i++)

Answer (score 0):

Your code made unsafe assumptions regarding arrays index size!

You should add few `if` conditions in order to get protection against [`IndexOutOfRangeException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.indexoutofrangeexception.aspx) or to use loops instead.

For example, how do you know that you have 4 elements here:

```
    lv.Text = items[0].ToString();
    lv.SubItems.Add(items[1].ToString());
    lv.SubItems.Add(items[2].ToString());
    lv.SubItems.Add(items[3].ToString());
```

Do it like that to be on the safe side:

```
for(int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
{
  lv.SubItems.Add(items[i])
}
```

Or at least check if you have 4 elements *first*:

```
if(items.Length == 4)
{
 lv.Text = items[0].ToString();
 lv.SubItems.Add(items[1].ToString());
 lv.SubItems.Add(items[2].ToString());
 lv.SubItems.Add(items[3].ToString());
}
```

Comment: hm, im still learning C# so could you give me an idea of what i could do?:P

Comment: @CameronHowsonn Well, did you use my suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, i had to go! I'll try them shortly and give you an update

Answer (score 0):

To avoid index out of range, refactor your code in a linq fashion to handle the dynamic nature of the data and never index again. Also by using Regular expressions to parse the data it can be beneficial situation.

Here is an approximation of the process using regular expressions and Linq and the removal of most of the indexing when adding sub items into the listview. Also the data extraction from the the regular expression pattern uses named match groups and no indexing.

*The overall concept is using a foreach instead of a for; per-se.*

## ListView Example

```
string data = "*Alpha/Beta/Gamma*Zebra/Delta/Tango";

string pattern = @"\*((?<SlashValues>[^/*]+)/?)+";

Regex.Matches(data, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)
     .OfType<Match>()
     .Select (mt => new {
                        LVI = new ListViewItem(),

                        SubItems = mt.Groups["SlashValues"].Captures
                                                           .OfType<Capture>()
                                                           .Select (cp => cp.Value),
                        }
            )
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(item => {
                        item.LVI.Text = item.SubItems.FirstOrDefault(),
                        LVI.AddRange(item.SubItems.Skip(1));
                        listView1.Items.Add(item);
                     });
```

---

## Regex Example

Taking out the ListViewItem code creates a better way to understand regex processing. Each match is a new ListView item where the pattern seeks a * as an anchor point. After that is found it then looks for multiple values divided by a / or * ultimately because it signals the end of the match and the start of a new match.

Try this is as a console app:

```
string data = "*Alpha/Beta/Gamma*Zebra/Delta/Tango";

// Put into group "SlashValues" into its capture collection
// [] is a set 
// [^] ^ in the set means NOT
// [^*/] Not a * or /
// [^*/]+ + means one or more 
//       which gets all characters up to a / or *
string pattern = @"\*((?<SlashValues>[^/*]+)/?)+";

Regex.Matches(data, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)
     .OfType<Match>()
     .Select (mt => mt.Groups["SlashValues"].Captures
                                            .OfType<Capture>()
                                            .Select (cp => cp.Value))
     .ToList()
     .ForEach(rs => Console.WriteLine (string.Join(", ", rs)));

/*
Alpha, Beta, Gamma
Zebra, Delta, Tango
*/
```